# Unity network player synchronization issues with HingeJoint(s)

Tags: unity, unity-networking, photon

I have a vehicle with custom wheels which are connected to it by the [HingeJoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint.html) components. Everything works perfectly when using this car in single-player mode. Wheels are actually as `Cylinder`s. They have `HingeJoint`s attached through which they are bound to the vehicle's `Rigidbody`. Then I set `JointMotor.force` and the wheels are getting rotated and the vehicle is moving. It all works very naturally in terms of physics, I don't need to emulate anything.

Still, there is an issue with network synchronization in multiplayer mode and I have no idea how to solve it.

It's said that the proper way to sync the position of a physical object is to use [`rigidbody.MovePosition()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html), but any manipulation with `Rigidbody` leads to the collapse of the vehicle hinge-joints. The only method that works is setting `transform.position` directly. But this is not recommended for physics and it doesn't allow to synchronize the vehicle smoothly with no twitching. Is there a way to solve this somehow?

I'm using [Photon](https://www.photonengine.com) for networking (if it matters in the question context).

Comment: In case my explanation is not clear, you can see a similar approach in this free asset: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/vehicles/children-s-wooden-toys-free-truck-pack-97476

Comment: Have you considered deleting the hinge joints on the replica, and spinning the wheels visually based on the point velocity of its attachment point? That way you still get physics-based wheels on the master, and plausible rotation on the replica.

Comment: It's probably the only way. I'm thinking of sending the angular velocity of each individual wheel to avoid doing these calculations since I'm not sure I can do it accurate enough to look natural.